# Change color of all elements of a certain type with a certain parent type

Tags: jquery

In my web page I'm trying to match all `<p>` elements with parent `<article>`, and change the text within all those matched `<p>` elements to white.

[image]

I have tried this:

```
$("article > p").each(function(){
    console.log($(this));
    $(this).css("color", "#ffffff");
});
```

...and even this:

```
$("p").each(function(){
    console.log($(this));
    $(this).css("color", "#ffffff");
});
```

...but neither works. I don't think the matching is even working because I'm not getting the number of log entries I would have expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: Inside the `<p>` elements there is nothing but raw text. No other `div`s or `span`s, etc. When I manually change the color of any `<p>` in Chrome dev tools, I get the expected result.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible fiddle? What you have looks like should would work.

Comment: hi, interesting, after running the script, do you see the new style in the inspector? You could try using addClass on the article also to change the color with a rule

Comment: Well when are you calling it? Do the elements exist when you call it? what does `console.log($("article > p").length);` show?

Comment: There is also no reason to loop. You can just do `$("article > p").css("color", "#ffffff");`

Comment: Thanks guys, you led me to the solution. From your questions I can see that my syntax was right, or close. And with the length check yielding 0, I discovered the contents are loading AFTER my script is running. So I probably just need a delay. When I run this in console after the page loads, it works perfectly: `$("article > p").css("color", "#ffffff");`

Comment: Are you doing this inside user interacted event or after $(document).ready??